# Getting error when trying to extract value for a specific key from different node levels

Tags: java, json

I am trying to extra value for `avatar` from all different node. My json looks like this

```
{  
   "page":1,
   "per_page":3,
   "total":12,
   "avatar":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/olegpogodaev/128.jpg",
   "total_pages":4,
   "data":[  
      {  
         "id":1,
         "first_name":"George",
         "last_name":"Bluth",
         "avatar":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/calebogden/128.jpg"
      },
      {  
         "id":2,
         "first_name":"Janet",
         "last_name":"Weaver",
         "avatar":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/josephstein/128.jpg"
      },
      {  
         "id":3,
         "first_name":"Emma",
         "last_name":"Wong",
         "avatar":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/olegpogodaev/128.jpg"
      }
   ],
   "user":{  
      "id":3,
      "first_name":"Emma",
      "last_name":"Wong",
      "avatar":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/olegpogodaev/128.jpg"
   }
}
```

I have tried following solution

```
public void getAllParentChildNodeAsMap(JSONObject jObject, Map<String, Object> result) throws JSONException {
        Iterator<String> iterator = jObject.keys();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            String key = (String) iterator.next();
            Object value = null;
             if (jObject.getJSONObject(key) instanceof JSONObject) {
                JSONObject jsonValue = jObject.getJSONObject(key);
                getAllParentChildNodeAsMap(jsonValue, result);
            } else {
                value = jObject.get(key);
            }

             if(key.equals("avatar")) {
                 result.put(key, value);
             }
        }
        log.info(result.values().toString());
    }
```

And it keeping giving me following error

```
org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["per_page"] is not a JSONObject.
    at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:782)
    at com.rnd.restapi.serenity.steps.CommonFacilities.getAllParentChildNodeAsMap(CommonFacilities.java:72)
    at com.rnd.restapi.serenity.steps.CommonFacilities$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$d9a1a28f.CGLIB$getAllParentChildNodeAsMap$5(<generated>)
    at com.rnd.restapi.serenity.steps.CommonFacilities$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$d9a1a28f$$FastClassByCGLIB$$bb25cc09.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.BaseMethodRunner.invokeMethod(BaseMethodRunner.java:10)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.NormalMethodRunner.invokeMethodAndNotifyFailures(NormalMethodRunner.java:20)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.runNormalMethod(StepInterceptor.java:390)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.testStepResult(StepInterceptor.java:161)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.intercept(StepInterceptor.java:72)
    at com.rnd.restapi.serenity.steps.CommonFacilities$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$d9a1a28f.getAllParentChildNodeAsMap(<generated>)
    at com.rnd.restapi.serenity.steps.CommonFacilities.getAllParentChildNode(CommonFacilities.java:64)
    at com.rnd.restapi.serenity.steps.CommonFacilities$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$d9a1a28f.CGLIB$getAllParentChildNode$4(<generated>)
    at com.rnd.restapi.serenity.steps.CommonFacilities$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$d9a1a28f$$FastClassByCGLIB$$bb25cc09.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.invokeMethod(StepInterceptor.java:478)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.executeTestStepMethod(StepInterceptor.java:463)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.runTestStep(StepInterceptor.java:438)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.runOrSkipMethod(StepInterceptor.java:179)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.testStepResult(StepInterceptor.java:166)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.intercept(StepInterceptor.java:72)
    at com.rnd.restapi.serenity.steps.CommonFacilities$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$d9a1a28f.getAllParentChildNode(<generated>)
    at com.rnd.restapi.tests.CountriesSearchTests.get_service_is_successful_and_status_code(CountriesSearchTests.java:32)
    at ✽.Get service is successful and status code 200(src/test/resource/feature/get.feature:7)
```

Comment: Instead of just asking "How do I do X?" please show your efforts. JSON parsing is so much asked topic you can find lot of tutorials in internet. We cannot help you to parse your entire json but rather a question like "This is how I am parsing JSON and this is the issue I am facing" etc.

Comment: Hey guys, I have updated the question. I have been looking the answer, but could not find an answer, thus posted. Any idea why is that error is happening?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `optJSONObject` method if you are not sure what kind of `JSON` node it is behind given key. `getJSONObject` method throws `org.json.JSONException` exception when given value is not `JSONObject`. Below you can find fixed method implementation:

```
void getAllParentChildNodeAsMap(JSONObject jObject, List<String> result) {
    for (String key : jObject.keySet()) {
        if (key.equals("avatar")) {
            result.add(jObject.getString(key));
            continue;
        }
        JSONObject value = jObject.optJSONObject(key);
        if (value != null) {
            getAllParentChildNodeAsMap(value, result);
            continue;
        }
        JSONArray array = jObject.optJSONArray(key);
        if (array != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject item = array.optJSONObject(i);
                if (item != null) {
                    getAllParentChildNodeAsMap(item, result);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is much useful to return `List` with `avatar` `URL`-es because for each `URL` `avatar` is a key.